# Sharepoint 2010: Rich Text Box won't allow insertion of picture from computer

Tags: 2010, infopath, rich-text

**I am having an issue trying to add an image to a rich text box in a new item.** I have added images to this form before by copying and pasting them. However, **it will not allow the insertion of images from computer.**

When I hover over the disabled button, the error message reads *"This control is currently disabled, you might not have the right permissions level to use this, you might need to select an object or item, or the control might not work in this context"*

**Any ideas on how to get this functionality?**

**note:** I created the form in InfoPath 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [found out](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-rich-text-box-0e3ec637-b9e2-4de6-9e36-a2641d7629d9?ocmsassetID=HP010080917&CorrelationId=a66d8125-0f08-4974-ab64-f1e1e67a571f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BM3) that inserting a picture into a rich text box from an InfoPath form is not supported. As a workaround, I'm planning on ditching my InfoPath form and just editing the default form view instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new field - select `Multiple Lines of Text - Enhanced Rich Text`.  Add the field to your view.

Then select **edit mode** see picture below - this switches the list to datasheet view (more like Excel), it permits inline editing.

[image: edit]

Then in your line, insert a picture.

[image: screen shot of field with picture]

Then you have a picture in your item - high 5!

### Notes

Update 1 - I should mention that I am using SP 2013.

Comment: It appears that this will work in a later version of SharePoint, but I'm using 2010. I tried switching to datasheet view, but I have the field with the rich-text box column hidden to prevent large messages from taking up too much list space. could there be another workaround?